# Flex 4.5 Error 1120: Access of undefined property. but i have created the variable. what's wrong?

Tags: apache-flex

```
private var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
[
    {
        media: "Facebook", 
        buzz: Math.random()*100, 
        percentage: Math.random()*100 
    },
    {
        media: "Twitter", 
        buzz: Math.random()*100, 
        percentage: Math.random()*100
    }
]
);
private function someMethod():void
{
    var myChart:BarChart = new BarChart();
    myChart.dataProvider = data;
    myChart.showDataTips = true;

    var vAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    vAxis.categoryField = "media";
    vAxis.dataProvider = data;
}
```

Sorry for this stupid question
but whats wrong with my code above..?
i have create the variables, but still got an error says **access of undefined property**
i want to try to create a simple chart, but stuck with this error

i try to create new flex app and re-type the code
but still got this error

Comment: `buzz1 Math.random()*100,  percentage1 Math.random()*100` are these typos or you are missing actual colon?

Comment: There is no error 1120 in your code, only lot of typos. Please be sure to post something related to your problem if you want someone to help you (I fixed few typos in your original post).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Don't ruin my reputation if my answer is wrong, but vague questions tend to get wrong answers.

Now to the answer:

From a glance at the code, your mistake appears to be in the way you are constructing the `ArrayCollection` data.

Your constructor has the signature:

```
ArrayCollection(Array, Array)
```

The actual ArrayCollection Constructor is like

```
ArrayCollection(Array)
```

Try fixing your code by conforming to that correct constructor,

```
private var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
[
    {
        media: "Facebook", 
        buzz: Math.random()*100, 
        percentage: Math.random()*100 
    }
,
    {
        media: "Twitter", 
        buzz: Math.random()*100, 
        percentage: Math.random()*100
    }
]
);
```

Comment: It isn't, but I've had the flex compiler give me some weird errors which set me off on the wrong track altogether. My answer was based on a look at the code given by the OP, and nothing seems wrong in what he's posted except the ArrayCollection construction.